# Pronominaladverb und *in*

Tags: grammaticality

Vor einer Weile stand in einem Artikel der folgende Teil eines Satzes:

> 1.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **in was** die Bundesregierung investieren soll, ...  **<- in etw. (Akk.) investieren**

Dem steht gegenüber:

> 2.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **woran** die Bundesregierung anknüpfen soll ...,   **<- an etw. (Akk.) anknüpfen**
>
> 3.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **worauf** die Bundesregierung vertrauen soll , ...  **<- auf etw. (Akk.) vertrauen**
>
> 4.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **wofür** die Bundesregierung eintreten soll, ...,   **<- für etw. (Akk.) eintreten**
>
> 5.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **wogegen** die Bundesregierung einschreiten soll, ...,   **<- gegen etw. (Akk.) einschreiten**
>
> 6.) ...
>
> 7.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, **worüber** die Bundesregierung nachdenken soll, ...,   **<- über etw. (Akk.) nachdenken**

Der Versuch, in 1.) ein Pronominaladverb zu verwenden, ergibt jedoch einen ungrammatischen Satz:

> 8.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, *worin die Bundesregierung investieren soll, ...

Das gleiche Phänomen zeigt sich z.B. bei *in etw. einwilligen*.

> 9.) Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, *worin die Bundesregierung einwilligen soll, ...

Wie ließe sich erklären, dass *in etw. investieren* oder *in etw. einwilligen* kein Pronominaladverb zulassen, während z.B. *an etw. (Akk.) anknüpfen*, *auf etw. vertrauen* u.v.a. es erfordern?

---

N.B.: Hinweise à la "In gesprochener Umgangssprache hört man in 2.) bis 7.) auch [Präp. + was] erklären **nicht**, warum 8.) und 9.) nicht existieren (können).

**Edit 11.02.19**: Bsp. 6.) der Einfachheit halber entfernt. Danke für den Hinweis, Olafant

Comment: "Wenn zum Beispiel diskutiert wird, womit die Bundesregierung rechnen kann, ..." - mit erfordert den Dativ.

Answer (score 3):

In den Wendungen *etwas in etwas investieren* oder *in etwas einwilligen* fordert die Präposition "in", da es sich um gerichtete Bewegungen handelt, den Akkusativ.

Das Adverb "worin" fragt allerdings nach dem Dativobjekt.

> Ich habe nichts, worin ich das Kleingeld aufbewahren könnte

(wegen *Ich bewahre das Kleingeld **im** Portemonnaie auf* - Dativ)

aber *nicht*

> <s>Ich habe nichts, worin ich das Kleingeld hineinlegen könnte</s>

(wegen *Ich lege das Kleingeld **in das** Portemonnaie* - Akkusativ)

Für die Frage nach dem Akkusativobjekt gibt es das (relativ ungebräuchliche) Adverb [wohinein](http://canoonet.eu/spelling/wohinein:Adv), das man wegen seiner Sperrigkeit gerne durch etwas anderes ersetzt.

Comment: Wieso fragt *worin* nach dem Dativ? Diese Unterscheidung war diesem Muttersprachler fremd. "wherein to invest" wäre meines Erachtens ebenso korrekt. Google sträubt sich, zeigt nur Ergebnisse für "where to invest". "wo Die BR investieren soll" wäre ebenso akzeptabel, schon allein weil "wor-in-in-vestieren" eine unschöne Redundanz enthält.Mit *rein*, *herein* hat *worin* vielleicht nichts zu tun, hört sich aber fast so an und stünde damit wenigstens Umgangssprachlich dem Beispiel entgegen. z.B. Man findet "das Ministerium investiert darin 70 Millionen Euro", sogar *darin investiert sein*.

Comment: @vectory Wieso das so ist? Weil es für gerichtete Bewegung mit Akkusativ eben "wohinein" gibt.

Comment: Das ist doch jetzt ein zirkuläres Argument.

Comment: Ich versuche immer noch, deine Frage zu verstehen. "Wo investieren" hat mit der Frage nichts zu tun. "darin" schon gar nicht, und das Englisch nicht Deutsch ist, brauchen wir, glaube ich, nicht zu diskutieren.

Comment: Alles ausflüchte. Die Antwort auf die Beispielfrage, "Wohinein sollte die Regierung einwilligen?" dürfte wohl kaum lauten, "Die Regierung sollte in eine Rechtschreibreform hineinwilligen".

Comment: @vectory Auf die Frage "worin sollte die Regierung einwilligen" kann ich nur antworten "im Parlament", aber nicht mit "in einen Vertrag". Also mit Dativ. Und ja, "hineinwilligen" ist kein mir bekanntes Wort, deswegen kann dein Satz auch nicht so lauten. Ich weiss ehrlich gesagt nicht, worauf du hinaus willst. Wenn du einen Kommentar abgibst, den ich auch verstehen kann, bin ich gerne bereit deine Frage zu beantworten oder gar meine Antwort zu modifizieren.

Comment: Du wolltest wohl fragen "Worin besteht das Problem?" :P Edit: und die Antwort ist "In meinem Unverständnis". Du meinst die korrekte Antwort auch mein Bsp. wäre etwa, "in \*dem Aktienmarkt", nicht wie es korrekt lauten würde, "den". Dann ist eventuel *wohin* oder für mich auch *worein* syntaktisch akzeptabel.

Comment: *\*hineinwilligen* wäre *hinein-einwilligen*, ich nahm an, das sei ofensichtlich.

Comment: @tofro  - Die Wiederholung des Ist-Zustands aus meiner Frage ist jetzt aber leider keine Erklärung. ;-) So wenig wie die Beschreibung aus GRIMM eine Erklärung ist. :-))

Comment: Dann frage ich mich, was denn eine Erklärung sein könnte - Sprache ist zum allergrößten Teil die *Dokumentation des Ist-Zustandes*. Wenn dir das nicht gefällt, solltest du dich mit Mathematik beschäftigen.

Comment: @tofro Es gibt ja auch andere Orte, an denen Fragen gestellt werden können, nicht wahr? :-) Dort lautete eine Antwort, eine **erklärende** Antwort: "Es gibt ein Präp.adv., das die Richtung anzeigt, also einen Akk. nach sich zieht, nämlich **worein**: *Wenn diskutiert wird, worein die Regierung investieren soll, ...*. Aus irgend einem Grund ist es jedoch nicht mehr in Gebrauch und wird gegenwärtig ersetzt durch: *... in was ...*." -  **Das** ist eine Erklärung, die dann allerdings

Comment: ... Verblüffendes zutage fördert: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/worein *Beispiele* 2.) "nichts, worein viel investiert werden müsste". Der Bsp.satz ohne *tag* wie 'veraltend', 'ungebräuchlich', überhaupt ohne *tag*

Comment: @multiplexetliber Das ist keine bessere Erklärung als die, die ich geliefert habe. Nur dass sie von dir kommt. Ich habe über "worein" nachgedacht, und auch den Duden-Eintrag gefunden, halte es aber für stark an der Grenze zur Umgangssprache, möglicherweise sogar drüber, auch wenn der Duden das nicht hingeschrieben hat. (Vielleicht deswegen hört es sich deshalb "gebräuchlicher" an.)

Answer (score 2):

Tofro hat das Rätsel schon gelöst, hier noch etwas historischer Kontext. Wie so oft hilft das Deutsche Wörterbuch weiter. Unter [in](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=in) heißt es:

> *von* in *trennt sich, was bei andern wörtern dieser gattung im deutschen nicht geschieht, die adverbialform ab, und zwar als eine doppelte, den beiden hauptrectionen der praeposition entsprechend. dem* in *als praep. des weilens, der ruhe geht zur seite für den begriff intus unser* inne, innen, *dem* in *als praep. der bewegung unser* ein *für den begriff intro* [...]

Unter [worin](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=worin) dann:

> *älter* **worinne**, **worinn**, *seit dem 15. jh. belegbare zusammensetzung aus* wo *(mhd.* wâr, wâ) *mit erhaltenem* r *vor vokalischem anlaut und adv.* in *aus ahd.* inni, inna, inne, *mhd.* inne, *lat.* intus. *die form* worin *ist demnach nicht aufzufassen als eine verschmelzung von* wo *mit präpositionalem* in, *das* in *des zweiten wortgliedes hat vielmehr, wie sich auch aus der bis zur wende des 18. und 19. jh. überaus häufigen schreibung* worinn *ergibt, als zu* inn, in *verkürztes adverb* inne *zu gelten* [...]

Man hat also adverbiales *in, inne(n)* (Komparativ: *inner*) mit der Bedeutung "innen" in Zusammensetzungen wie:

> *darin, worin, hierin; d(a)rinnen; innehaben, innehalten* (daraus *Inhalt*); *innerlich*

und adverbiales *ein* mit der Bedeutung "hinein" in solchen wie:

> *(he)rein*, *eindringen*, *Eindruck*, bairisch *eini* (< *ein hin*)

Demnach sollte *worin* nur dort stehen können, wo *in* mit dem Dativ steht.

Daher auch der folgende Kontrast:

> Ich stell mich mal daneben (=neben + Akk.) und schau dir zu.
> Und du stehst daneben (=neben + Dat.) und guckst blöd!
>
> Steht darin (=in + Dat.) auch, wie man das repariert?
> Ich schreib das da jetzt rein (=in + Akk.).

Comment: (+1) Sehr gut erklärt. Und es widerlegt natürlich, was ich in meiner Antwort geschrieben habe. :-)

Comment: (+1) Sehr schöne Ergänzung zu meiner Antwort, danke. Ich habe nicht daran gedacht, den Grimm zu Rate zu ziehen.

Comment: @David Vogt Der Rückgriff auf GRIMM ist natürlich immer prima ;-), nur: Ist das, was du zitiert hast (und was ich längst selbst gelesen hatte), eine Erklärung, oder doch nur die Beschreibung des Status quo? :-)

Comment: Diachron gesehen eine Erklärung (*worin* aus *wo(r)* plus *inne*), synchron eine Beschreibung (*worin* nur da, wo auch *in* mit dem Dativ stehen kann).